Conditionally add some data members to a base class, conditioned on the presence of a derived data member
I would like to conditionally add some data members to a base class, conditioned on the presence of a derived data member.
In the below example, Extra is the base class template, which will be switched on the template parameter Enable.
The consteval function enable is used to detect the presence of the derived data member, the return value of which will be used to select which version of Enable we want.
Foo is the base class to which we want to add the extra functionality, and Bar is the derived type which declares the requisite member which we are using the enable the extra functionality.
#include <iostream>

template<bool Enable>
struct Extra
{
    static constexpr bool is_enabled = false;
};

template<>
struct Extra<true>
{
    static constexpr bool is_enabled = true;

    int extra { 42 };
};

template<typename T>
consteval bool enable()
{
    if constexpr (requires { T::enable_extra; })
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

template<typename T>
struct Foo : Extra<enable<T>()>
{
    using Base = Extra<enable<T>()>;
    using Base::is_enabled;

    void eval()
    {
        if constexpr (is_enabled)
        {
            if (static_cast<T*>(this)->enable_extra)
                std::cout << "extra=" << Base::extra << '\n';
        }
    }
};

struct Bar : Foo<Bar>
{
    const bool enable_extra = true;
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    b.eval();
    return 0;
}

Suffice to say it doesn't work, and enable<T>() evaluates to false at the point at which it is called.
My current hypothesis is that this is due to Bar being incomplete at the point at which Foo is instantiated, and therefore T::enable_extra doesn't yet exist, so the if constexpr evaluates to false.
Is what I'm trying to do here even possible? Am I able to add base class functionality based on the presense of a member in the derived class?

I suppose struct Bar : Foo<true> {}; as the simpler alternative is not what you want

It is what I will have to do if I cannot solve this question, but given the data member will have to exist in all the derived classes I am creating, it's a bit redundant

you might look for CRTP, your hypothesis is correct and its something often faced with crtp

Beyond the possibility to achieve your goal it's wording feels strange. Base class (at least for public inheritance) is the common interface of all inherited class. It looks like you'd like that if some client is adding a child with some property, all of a sudden, other already existing inherited classes see there base change. I don't clearly understand the functionality you desires and I feel that you're going for the wrong design.

I doubt this is possible. Diagonal argument: struct Bar : Foo<Bar> {  const bool enable_extra = sizeof(Foo<Bar>) < sizeof(int); }; Here, if Foo<Bar> has int member, Foo::enable_extra is false, and so that member shouldn't be there. And vice versa.

I would consider resolving the "incomplete type" issue of CRTP by not using CRTP here. The cyclic type dependency between Bar and Foo seems quite artificial and unnecessary. Why not defining struct Bar { /*...*/ }; first (no inheritance from Foo), then defining template<typename T> struct Foo : public T { /*...*/ };, and use Foo<Bar> in the rest of the program ?

I'm not sure if this meets your requirements, but if the value of extra doesn't need to be in a class, this might work.
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
concept has_enable_extra = requires
{
    { T::enable_extra } -> std::same_as<const bool&>;
};

template <has_enable_extra T>
static constexpr int extra = 42;

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    void eval()
    {
        if constexpr (has_enable_extra<T>)
        {
            if (static_cast<T*>(this)->enable_extra)
                std::cout << "extra=" << extra<T> << '\n';
        }
    }
};

struct Bar : Foo<Bar>
{
    const bool enable_extra = true;
};
static_assert(has_enable_extra<Bar>);

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    b.eval();
    return 0;
}

If the value needs to be in a class, you can't conditionally have the member variable because of what you said about Bar being incomplete. You can, however, make that variable a std::optional. If the presence of has_enable_extra is checked in the constructor definition, it should work. Again, I'm not sure if this meets your requirements. I'm just trying to offer some alternatives that might help.
template <typename T>
struct Extra
{
    Extra()
    {
        if constexpr (has_enable_extra<T>)
        {
            extra = 42;
        }
    }
    std::optional<int> extra = {};
};

